# Chord extensions

Tags: chord-theory

I notice a pattern in what extensions work with what chords.

- 11ths don't complement major/dominant chords.
- 13ths don't in minor chords
- and 9ths don't in diminished chords.

Is there an analytical reason for this?

Comment: To my ears all these extensions are fine. Although, you would often leave out the major third of an 11th chord, to avoid the dissonant minor 9th between major third and 11th.

Comment: 11ths will complement dominant chords - they have/need the b7 in them. 9ths don't feature in diminished chords. Unless you mean b9ths, which stand on their own.

Comment: Ah yes, good point @Tim. An 11th sounds pretty bad if a major7 is in the chord, but fine with a b7 (dominant 7th). A #11 sounds good with either major or dominant 7th.

Comment: @bob broadley This is subjective, but to most peoples ears 11ths in major chords simply do not sound harmonious. If you remove the third, its not the same chord, so that doesnt count. Likewise with 13ths in minor chords and 9ths in diminished.

Comment: How are you spelling 11ths and  9ths in dim chords, please?

Comment: @ Tim Exactly where those intervals fall naturally in the scale. No altered extensions, no dropping thirds.

Comment: So your 11ths will have a 1,3,5,7,9 and 11? And in dim chords there are no 9ths. A full dim chord will have 1.b3,b5,bb7.

Comment: It sounds like you all are talking about things as they are handled within the Classical world.  Would that be accurate?  Otherwise I would largely disagree with a lot of these comments.

Comment: @Basstickler - re-reading, I think the OP means a basic chord (triad), with something like an 11th note added. Cadd11, F#add13, maybe? But D dim add9? Not sure.

Comment: @Tim i meant 7th chords, so a half diminished chord with a ninth, but I'm not sure if that makes a difference Either way. Also analyzing this from a Jazz or classical perspective also doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @William - It does make a difference.  The Classical approach is typically handled very differently, where they would refer to a 13th chord, it would mean that it was a chord built from that scale degree, within the context of that key, so a minor 13th chord built on scale degree 2 would have a major 13 but built on scale degree 6 would have a minor 13.  The Jazz convention would not take this approach.  If it says 13 with no other chord symbols (in Jazz) it would mean it was a dominant chord with a 13.

Comment: @William - Also, Jazz would typically not omit the 3rd from the chord to prevent the dissonance of a major chord with a natural 11.  They would ultimately probably think of that as a different chord altogether, as it would likely change the function of the chord.  Things are definitely referred to and handled a bit differently between Jazz and Classical, as much as there is some overlap.

Comment: @Basstickler There's no fundamental difference between classical and jazz theory. Theres just different names for things. My question is not different when analyzed from either perspective.

Comment: @William - Jazz theory is derived from Classical theory, so they are indeed quite similar, however, they approach music in a very different manner, with contradictory conventions.  I studied Jazz and Classical in college, focusing on theory, and I can tell you with 100% certainty that this would make a difference when we get beyond the basic concept of the question and on to execution within the context.  So it changes the answer if you want details about how/why.  Short answer is dissonance caused by a b9, which would be very atypical for Jazz and not as atypical for Classical.

Answer (score 3):

Extensions, also known as Tensions, are handled a little differently in Jazz than Classical, so context will be important here to some extent but most often when people are asking about this, they are asking about it from a Jazz perspective, so I'll assume that's the case and answer focusing on Jazz.  Alterations are categorized separately but are generally used in the same way.  An Alteration is basically an Extension that has been altered, such as b9, #9, #11, b13.  I will be referring to Extensions and Alterations in my answer as Extensions in general but there are differences between their importance, which I will address later as well.

Extensions are often described as being Available Extensions.  Extensions are considered available if they are a whole step above a chord tone.  This rule generally applies to chords that do not fulfill a dominant function (Fully Diminished chords are typically considered to have a dominant function, as they are used to resolve to a tonal center).  Major chords will have available tension of 9, #11 and 13 and Minor chords will have 9, 11 and 13.  It's also important to note that within the Jazz world, a Minor 7 b5 is not considered to have a dominant function but a predominant function and would therefore employ a 9, not the b9 that would occur naturally.

There is one important "rule" when using tensions on non-dominant chords: any tension that has a chord tone a half step above it, should be voiced above that chord tone.  I put rule in quotes because there are no rules in music, so you can do it if it works for you in your music, however it would not conform to the standards of the genre and should be avoided if you're playing in a traditional group.  The reasoning behind this has to do with dissonance and function.  When placing the chord tone above the tension, you end up creating a b9 between them, which is very dissonant and essentially changes the function of the chord, requiring a resolution that the intended chord would/should not need.  This b9 dissonance outlines the reasoning behind why tensions a whole step above a chord tone are considered available as well.  You can also place the two notes directly next to each other, which creates a b2, but you'll notice the textural difference in doing so and can choose to apply it appropriately.

The major difference between Extensions and Alterations has to do with their importance to the chord they are applied to.  We typically consider Alterations to be more telling of the chord than extensions.  For instance, 9 can be found on a Major or Minor chord but b9 would only be applied to a dominant functioning chord.  Similarly, #11 would be used for Major chords but 11 could be applied to Minor and Diminished.

I was taught of a hierarchy by a teacher many years ago, specifically for Jazz accompanists, ie, those voicing the chords and having a bass player playing the roots.

1. Third and Seventh; 2. Alterations; 3. Extensions; 4. Fifth; 5. Root

You can think about this in terms of what gives the most information about the chord.  3 and 7 can tell you a lot about the chord, where the root tells you nothing (assuming no tonal context).  The 5, specifically a Perfect 5, as b5 or #5 would be considered alterations, tells you nothing about the chord, other than what it isn't (ie, any chord that doesn't have a P5); because of this (as well as voicing considerations), 5 is often omitted.  From there we have the Extensions and Alterations and I described above how Alterations are more telling than Extensions.

In short, you're basically hearing the dissonance caused by these Extensions that cause a b9 between voices and how they muddy the texture and can subvert the function of a chord.  If Extensions and Alterations are treated appropriately, they can be used to add great texture to the harmony, without subverting the function, even outside the Jazz world, however uncommon that tends to be.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's because those extensions fall a minor second away from stronger chord tones, so they confuse the tonality. They are usually either not played, or altered.

In half dim chords, they are usually skipped. (11 good, 9 not so good)

In a major chord or dom chord, the 11 is usually sharp 11 or dropped (13 good, b13 good too if the 5th is altered)

In a minor chord, the 13th is usually voiced as a natural 13th if the seventh is major or missing (or as a a 6/9 chord) or left out if the 7th is lowered. (9th and 11th good) Generally that note is called a 6 if there is no 7 present, and a 13 if the Maj7 is in there as in a MinorMajor7 voicing.

Good books on jazz/contemporary arranging will go into this in detail.

HTH!

Comment: Consider the following search term for your self-study: "avoid notes".  From my own notes... “avoid notes” may be defined as those tensions which create a minor ninth interval (or less) above a chord tone. However, for dominant chords, the ♭9 and ♭13 are exceptions to this rule. Avoid notes also include those tensions which create a tritone interval within a non-dominant chord. For dominant chords, the ♭13 the ♮5 should be mutually exclusive; use one or the other, but not both.

Comment: @KirkA - I can't say that I've heard the tritone rule before.  In particular, #11 creates a tritone with the root and b3 and 13 create a tritone.  Both of these seem to be very common.